# getParam questions

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The var have_calibration is always evaluating to false. I also tried this with just

```
ros::NodeHandle nh
```

and in place of that

```
ros::param::get
```

and

```
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  // kill program, if we don't have a camera calibration
  bool have_calibration = true;
  have_calibration = have_calibration && nh.getParam("/Cam_fx", Cam_fx);
  have_calibration = have_calibration && nh.getParam("/Cam_fy", Cam_fy);
  have_calibration = have_calibration && nh.getParam("/Cam_cx", Cam_cx);
  have_calibration = have_calibration && nh.getParam("/Cam_cy", Cam_cy);
  have_calibration = have_calibration && nh.getParam("/Cam_s", Cam_s);
```

from parameter server:

```
PARAMETERS
 * /Cam_cx: 0.500156
 * /Cam_cy: 0.515833
 * /Cam_fx: 0.0.836562
 * /Cam_fy: 1.1233333
 * /Cam_s: 0.4
```

I loaded the parameters using: in launch file.

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find skimap_ros)/SkimapPtamFixParams.yaml"/>
```

There appears to be some kind of syntax or value error in the yaml file....but it is not reported . I will report back on the cause soon.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273392/getparam-questions/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The value

```
/Cam_fx: 0.0.836562
```

is causing the parameter sever to become corrupt can someone please verify this.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-10-18**:
perhaps it does not see it as numeric and that causes the test to fail...but there should have been an error msg some where..no?

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-11-05**:
`getParam` doesn't display an error message. It indicates failure by returning false, allowing the user (you) to decide what to do. It seems you have answered your own question, so please select this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark.